# Scanf and Address Operator (&) not working inside for loop

Tags: c, variables, scanf

I have an assignment and I was wondering why when I compile this code and run it, the `scanf("%d", &temp_pin)` doesn't store the data in an address. I know this because in the next statement of `printf("%d", temp_pin)` I'm just given random variables. I have another scanf statement in the earlier lines of code that work and I`m just stumped as to why this one doesn't. Many thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
//Deceleration of Variables
int option;
int pin [4]={1, 2, 3, 4};
int temp_pin [4];
int new_pin [4];
int temp_new_pin [4];
int correct;
int incorrect;



do
{
    printf("Please enter which option you wish to operate\n\n");
    printf("1. Enter your pin\n");
    printf("2. Change your pin\n");
    printf("3. Display the number of times the PIN was entered: \n  Successfully\n  Unsuccessfully\n");
    printf("4. Exit Program\n\n");

    scanf("%d", &option);

    if (option == 1)
    {
    printf("\nPlease Enter Your PIN\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        scanf(" %d", &temp_pin);
        printf(" %d", temp_pin);

        if (temp_pin==pin)
        {
            printf("\nYour PIN is correct\n");
        }

        if (temp_pin != pin)
        {
            printf("\nYour PIN is incorrect\n");
        }
     }//End For
     }//End If

} // end do
while(option != 4);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `temp_pin` is array, but you treat it as a scalar. Not sure if it will even compile.

Comment: @EugeneSh. It just gives me a warning when I try to compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `temp_pin` declared as an *array* of integers, so `&temp_pin` is a pointer to an array and has type `int (*)[4]`.  The `%d` format specifier expects an `int *`.

Similarly, when printing you pass the array `temp_pin` which decays to a pointer to the first element, and that address is what is being printed.

Change the type of `temp_pin` and the other variables declared as arrays to `int` and remove the loop.

```
int pin = 1234;
int temp_pin;
int new_pin;
int temp_new_pin;

...

if (option == 1)
{
    printf("\nPlease Enter Your PIN\n");

    scanf(" %d", &temp_pin);
    printf(" %d", temp_pin);

    if (temp_pin==pin)
    {
        printf("\nYour PIN is correct\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nYour PIN is incorrect\n");
    }
}//End If
```

Comment: This is not what the OP attempts to do. It seems from the code that they try to read a pin that consists of 4 numbers (for some reason). Perhaps each int is supposed to hold a digit. The conceptual problem here lies in the attempt to read an array with one `scanf` call, as you might do in other high-level languages. And the same problem with comparison operations.

Answer (score 1):

If I could make one suggestion it would be changing all the integer arrays into integers. This would fix all of your problems. However, if your assignment requires the use of integer arrays please follow the code below.

Currently you are setting only the first element of temp_pin equal to the user input. The line `scanf(" %d", &temp_pin);` actually stores an integer into `temp_pin[0]`.

Since the pin size is 4, you would need to read in 4 separate integers to store in the array. I would suggest using a for loop that can set the values of `temp_pin[0], temp_pin[1], temp_pin[2], temp_pin[3]`

Logically, I would also suggest error checking each integer, since an integer can be from size -32,768 to 32,767. Currently an integer array with the elements `3300,55,12,15` would be a valid pin.

The value you are given in this line `printf(" %d", temp_pin);` is not random variables. This is the address of temp pin. In order to print the values stored in temp_pin you would need to iterate through each element in the array and print it individually.

For your compare statement `if (temp_pin==pin)`, this would never result in true since it is comparing addresses. Again the proper fix for this would be to iterate through both lists simultaneously and compare each element.

Answer (score 0):

You attempt to read an array with one `scanf` call, but it does work like that in c. Note that `temp_pin` is already an address of the first element in the array. 
The line

```
scanf("%d", temp_pin);
```

is equivalent to the line

```
scanf("%d", &(temp_pin[0]));
```

and it reads the value and stores it at `temp_pin[0]`.

In order to read the whole array you'll need to do something like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<4; i++) scanf("%d", &(temp_pin[i]));
```

The same story with the comparison. You can't compare two arrays with one `==` operation. The expression `temp_pin == pin` compares the addresses which will always be different despite the actual values that are stored in those arrays. In order to compare two arrays  you'll need to do something like this:

```
int isEqual = 1; // a flag for whether arrays are equal 
for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    if (temp_pin[i] != pin[i]) {
        isEqual = 0; 
    }
}
if (isEqual) printf("pins are the same\n");
else printf("pins are not the same\n");
```